# Decrypt encrypted binary file in java ( AES_CTR mode)

Tags: java, python, pycrypto

I know this question have been asked before. I just need a direction to complete these code. It would be very helpfull if anyone could point out the problem in my code

Here is is the Java code for decryption

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.File;
class Decode{
    public static void main(String []args){
    try{
        Decode.decrypt();
        System.out.println("Decrypted");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
public static void decrypt() throws Exception {
    byte[] initialIV;
    final byte[] buf = new byte[128];
    final Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");

    final InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/home/neki/python/encVideo.mp4");



    byte[] buffer = new byte[16];
    is.read(buffer);


    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,new SecretKeySpec("1234567890123456".getBytes(), "AES"),new IvParameterSpec(buffer));

    final OutputStream os = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/home/neki/python/javaDecVideo.mp4"), c);
    while (true) {
        int n = is.read(buf);
        if (n == -1) break;
            os.write(buf, 0, n);
    }
    os.close(); is.close();
}
}
}
```

and here is the python code to encrypt the file

```
import os, random, struct
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from os import urandom
from Crypto.Util import Counter
def encrypt_file(key, in_filename, out_filename=None, chunksize=128):


if not out_filename:
    out_filename = in_filename + '.enc'

iv = '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0'
encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter = lambda : iv)
filesize = os.path.getsize(in_filename)

with open(in_filename, 'rb') as infile:
    with open(out_filename, 'wb') as outfile:
        # outfile.write(struct.pack('<Q', filesize))
        outfile.write(iv)

        while True:
            chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
            if len(chunk) == 0:
                break

            outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))
encrypt_file("1234567890123456".encode(),"/home/neki/python/Eduaid.mp4","/home/neki/python/encVideo.mp4")
```

I have also found some ideas in stackoverflow. but can't able to understand very well.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have configured this cipher is highly insecure. **DO NOT USE THIS CODE.**

By setting:

```
counter = lambda : iv
```

while initializing the AES cipher in Python, you have forced AES-CTR to use the exact same counter for every block. This reduces the cipher from AES-CTR to a simple rolling XOR. Observe:

```
>>> key = "abcd1234abcd1234"
>>> iv = '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0'
>>> encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter = lambda : iv)
>>> encryptor.encrypt("example block 01")
'\xda\x7f\x00\xbdp\x1c\xe4\xf3=|\x88\xe2\xe5%\x80\xab'
>>> encryptor.encrypt("example block 01")
'\xda\x7f\x00\xbdp\x1c\xe4\xf3=|\x88\xe2\xe5%\x80\xab'
>>> encryptor.encrypt("example block 02")
'\xda\x7f\x00\xbdp\x1c\xe4\xf3=|\x88\xe2\xe5%\x80\xa8'
```

Notice that:

1. Encrypting the same block repeatedly results in the same output.
2. Encrypting similar blocks results in similar output. (Technically, `a XOR b = E(a) XOR E(b)`.)

To fix this, you need to use the `Counter` class you have already imported:

```
encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=Counter.new(128))
```

Once you have configured AES-CTR correctly, your existing Java code should be able to decrypt it.

However, note that **this mode is still insecure** if the same key is reused to encrypt multiple files. You must use a different key for every file.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have changed it to """Counter.new(128)""" .  But it still can not able to decrypt in java. ( FYI : But i can bale to dycrypt it in python)

Comment: I think java "new IvParameterSpec(buffer)" and python Counter.new(128) both generating different value. cant figured it out